# Exception out of the blue (exception on an empty space) in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Can a C++ exception come "out of nowhere"? Not literally. Does anybody know non obvious special cases when C++ runtime can throw exception from a place that is not an explicit call of the function?

Platform specific experiences and information about implementations that deviate from the standard are interesting also.

**Please do not post answers about:**

1. Macroprocessor tricks that hide function calls;
2. Default constructors;
3. Destructors;
4. Overloaded operators;
5. Overloaded conversions;
6. Unoverloaded operators `new` and `new[]`;

MSVC provides an option that allows to handle hardware exceptions (GPF, division by zero, etc) as C++ exceptions. Can anybody comment on how this is handled on other platforms or maybe somebody knows a right place in the standard that speaks about this?

To the guy who downvoted this question: Please, have courage to tell what is wrong here.

Answer (score 3):

No, no, and there isn't one, it's only an MSVC option. Only Windows treats hardware errors like exceptions, and these structured exceptions are only converted into C++ exceptions if you ask for it. The other platforms use signals.

Exceptions do not come out of nowhere. They come when you, or the well-defined places in the Standard library (and a couple in the language like `dynamic_cast`) throw them. The C++ runtime does not throw them for lolsies. If you have an exception of unknown source, then get a better debugger and learn how to use it until it doesn't have an unknown source.

Comment: These are nice considerations. Although I would like to see exact list of `well-defined places in the Standard library` and `couple of places in the language`. Can you list them? Do you know specific place in the standard that clearly states that exceptions cannot be raised in other situations?

Comment: No. The Standard does not exhaustively list every time and place an exception may not be raised, as that would be an infinite list. It merely lists the times and places where exceptions may be raised.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was kind of thinking myself.